# How to create a rest service in apache camel that routes to a consumer endpoint?

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, xmpp

I am trying  to build a chat using xmpp as producer and as consumer.
I have the following code:

```
rest("/xmppchat")
        .get()
        
        .to("direct:jennychat");
        
        from("direct:jennychat")
        .process(new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
             
                exchange.getIn().setBody("hi maro");
           }
        })
        .to("xmpp://JID:port?participant=JID&password=OneTeam2020");
        
//this route is not working
        from("xmpp://JID:port?participant=JID&password=OneTeam2020")
        
        .setBody(constant("I will win!\n Your Superman."))
        .log("${body}");
```

however, the second route is not starting because in the `rest` part I did not route to it, but I don t know how to do that since I cannot use the `direct` component in `from`
So any idea how to do that?
Thank you

Comment: You can use direct in from. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Hello @Namphibian, I cannot use ```direct``` in ```from``` because this is the endpoint ```from("xmpp://JID:port?participant=JID&password=OneTeam2020")``` that I will be routing to, so I need to use ```xmpp``` and not ```direct```